# Why does the python IDLE interpreter put a newline at the end of each compiled file?

Tags: python

I was wondering why that occurs... Is it something to do with reading the file by the interpreter, or a unintentional thing... Maybe it's just for EOU... (Ease Of Use). Who knows...
I have tried to pre-newline the file to check what happens and it stays unchanged. Also, putting 2 or more newlines at the end of the document does alter the output, so the amount of newlines stays the same.

Comment: Text files on Unix-like systems are supposed to end with a newline; some standard text processing tools get upset if you give them a file that doesn't end in a newline.

Comment: In UNIX, a text file must end with a `\n`. I assume IDLE just does this with all operating systems for compatibility.